# Where can I find microsoft-azure-storage.jar?

Tags: android, azure

I am a newer in Azure,
I'd like to import com.microsoft.azure.storage.*,
and this class is in "microsoft-azure-storage.jar",

Please tell me how to get this I cannot find any directions.

Comment: For example, I found [this link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-java-how-to-use-blob-storage/) in 30 seconds using a Google search on `import com.microsoft.azure.storage`. It in turn links to [the project's GitHub repository](https://github.com/azure/azure-storage-java), which has instructions for adding the library to your project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to close this out with a proper answer (vs a link in a comment):

First let me point you to where information lives, regarding Azure and SDKs. If you visit [azure.microsoft.com](http://azure.microsoft.com), there's a documentation link (near top of page) that will give you docs on all the Azure features. There's also a Downloads link, providing download info on all the SDKs. It's here that you'll see links to Java downloads, for Windows, Mac, and Linux (which show how to set up Maven dependencies). There's also an additional Documentation link under Java, where you'll find lots more info, including links to github. *There's also an Android SDK download on that page. You tagged your question as [[image]android](/questions/tagged/android), so this may be of interest to you.*

Assuming you want to jump straight to github: All Azure SDKs are located at https://github.com/azure, including the various Java SDKs. The Azure storage SDK for Java is located at https://github.com/azure/azure-storage-java. As shown in that repo's readme, you can install via Maven, git clone+compile, or zip.

Maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
    <artifactId>azure-storage</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Git clone (and using Maven to compile):

```
git clone git://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-java.git
cd ./azure-storage-java/microsoft-azure-storage
mvn compile
```

Zip: Download the latest, [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-java/archive/master.zip), and unzip.